# Get a permission denied error when trying to empty a file inside a shell script

Tags: shell, redirect

I use the following command to empty a file:

```
cat /dev/null > myfile.txt
```

It works when hitting this command directly into the shell.

As I have multiple files to empty, I'd like to make a script to execute this command. Here runs my script :

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /dev/null 1> myfile.txt
```

Then I get an error saying that myfile.txt permission denied.

Thanks for your help in advance !

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious but do you have write permission on the file? Also how about `rm myfile.txt; touch myfile.txt` instead ?

Comment: Why did you change `>` to `1>`?  It shouldn't matter, but it seems odd.  Are you running the script from the same command line where you ran the `cat` command?  If not, how exactly are you running it?  Did you do `chmod +x` on your script?  (If not, the error message should refer to the script name, not to `myfile.txt`.)

Comment: add an `ls -l myfile.txt` just before the `cat ...` line. This should show you the permissions and owner/group of the file. This will show you why you can't delete the file. Good luck.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `cat /dev/null` part.  `: > myfile.txt` works just as well (it's the `>`, not the `cat` that does anything)

Comment: @evilotto: You don't even need the colon.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these

```bsh
> myfile.txt

: > myfile.txt

: | tee myfile.txt
```